# Find area enclosed by curves $x^3 + y^3 = x^2 + y^2$, $x$-axis and $y$-axis using Divergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, parametrization, divergence-theorem

I know how to deal with the axis part, but I struggle solving the integral with the curve $$x^3 + y^3 = x^2 + y^2$$ I tried to parametrize the curve using polar coordinates.
$$x = r(t)\cos(t)$$
$$y = r(t)\sin(t)$$

where $$r(t) = \frac{1}{\cos^3(t)+\sin^3(t)}$$
Using $$\iint_S 1 \,d(x,y) = \int_{\partial S} x\,dy = $$ $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(t)}{\cos^3(t)+\sin^3(t)} \cdot\frac{\cos(t)(\cos^3(t)+\sin^3(t))+\sin(t)(3\cos^2(t)\sin(t)-3\sin^2(t)\cos(t))}{(\cos^3(t)+\sin^3(t))^2} \, dt $$ $${}+\int_{\pi/2}^\pi 0 \, dt + \int_\pi^{2\pi} 0 \, dt$$

But I can't solve the first integral. I tried to find another parametrization but wasn't succesful. I'm sure there is a simplier way to solve this than computing the integral. Can you give me some advice about the easier parametrization or hint how to solve the integral?

Comment: Do you have to use divergence theorem for this problem or can I solve it with different methods?

Comment: I used an indexing parameter field approach. I got 3 different values from the integration that were close to ${8/5, 0, 1/2}$ Is there any way to narrow this down?

Comment: I am supposed to use the divergence theorem so most probably I'm looking for another way to parametrize the curve to get easier integral.

Comment: Seing the plot looks like a line with slope $-1$ I considered $\frac{\pi}{4}$ rotation $x=u+v, y=u-v$ and the thing [simplifies to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28u%2Bv%29%5E3%2B%28u-v%29%5E3%3D%28u%2Bv%29%5E2%2B%28u-v%29%5E2) $v^2=-u^2\frac{u-1}{3u-1}$

Comment: Try setting $y=tx$.  Then you get $x=\frac{1+t^2}{1+t^3},\ 0<t<\infty$